# TinyOS: RssiDemo

Tags: java, clang, tinyos, nesc

I'm trying to run the RssiDemo example of TinyOS which is situated under the *apps/tutorials/RssiDemo* folder.

My problem is that when I try to generate the *RssiMsg.java* class with *make* i obtain the following message:

> clang: error: language not recognized: 'nesc'

The Makefile is the following:

```
all: RssiDemo.class

RssiMsg.class: RssiMsg.java
javac $<

RssiDemo.class: RssiDemo.java RssiMsg.java
javac $^

RssiMsg.java: ../RssiDemoMessages.h
nescc-mig java -java-classname=RssiMsg $< RssiMsg -o $@
```

Can someone give me some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue, the problem seems to occur here
`nescc-mig java -java-classname=RssiMsg $< RssiMsg -o $@`.

The man page for nescc states that nescc is an extension for gcc. However, on OS X, clang runs instead of gcc. So instead of running gcc you are running clang.

If you have Mac ports you can install mp-gcc with `$sudo port install mp-gcc46` and then run `$sudo port select gcc mp-gcc46`. Trying running `make <platform>` again and it should hopefully work.

Here's a guide on installing TinyOS on OS X just in case :)
http://olafland.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/tinyos-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/

Answer (score 0):

compile on SendingMote and RssiBase folders with:

```
make <platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to java folder in RssiDemo. Type following command
1. **make**       //This will create RssiDemo.java, RsssiDemo.class and more
2.  $ java RssiDemo -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:iris
This will display output on terminal

For more understanding go to this link:
http://hanyulius.blogspot.in/2012/12/rssi-example-on-tinyos.html?showComment=1440142454239#c8425927168298978754